# Is there a way to build dynamic models in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, api

I am currently building a project in Django, and I was wondering if is there a way to build a dynamic model. I want to create a model with a group of user, and the table structure is the following:

- Group Name
- User 1
- User 2
- User 3
- User ...

But I want to make users dynamic, I mean, if the group has only 2 users the model will only put 2 users fields in the model, and if the group has 10 user the model put 10 users fields in the model.

Does someone know a way to do this? Is it even possible?

I hope I made it clear enough for you guys!
If you have any questions please post in the comments and I will answer as fast as I can.
Sorry for the english tho! Not my main language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this way.
One group may have many users and one user can be in may groups you can use `ManyToManyField`.

So you need something like:

```
# default user model or custom user model
class User():
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer! I didn't really tought about that, but makes sense! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible in django. because the models should be clear to make tables in database. but you can handle this with many-to-many relationship. as the django documents say [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! I didn't think about that way to do that, but makes sense!